# Converting binary reading function from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, c#-4.0

I am honestly really confused on reading binary files in C#.
I have C++ code for reading binary files:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen(filename, "rb");    
uint n = 1024;
uint readC = 0;
do {
    short* pChunk = new short[n];
    readC = fread(pChunk, sizeof (short), n, pFile);    
} while (readC > 0);
```

and it reads the following data:

```
-156, -154, -116, -69, -42, -36, -42, -41, -89, -178, -243, -276, -306,...
```

I tried convert this code to C# but cannot read such data. Here is code:

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
{
     sbyte[] buffer = new sbyte[1024];                
     for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
     {
         buffer[i] = reader.ReadSByte();
     }                
}
```

and i get the following data:

```
100, -1, 102, -1, -116, -1, -69, -1, -42, -1, -36
```

How can i get similar data?

Comment: In C++, you're reading each entity as a `short`, which is 2 bytes , whereas in C#, you're reading each entity as an `sbyte` which is 1 byte.

Comment: @Jason surely in C++ the size of `short` is not fully defined ;p But: I don't disagree. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know, no C++ experience ;/

Comment: In the C++ example you're reading short data types, while in the C# example you're using a signed byte, the data range is much smaller.  Have you tried changing     sbyte to     short in the C# example?

Comment: Indeed, -178, -243, -306, etc are completely outside the `sbyte` range - so that is never going to work as `sbyte`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short is not a signed byte, it's a signed 16 bit value.

```
 short[] buffer = new short[1024];                
 for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
     buffer[i] = reader.ReadInt16();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in C++ you're reading shorts and in C# you're reading signed bytes (that's why SByte means). You should use `reader.ReadInt16()`

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ code reads 2 bytes at a time (you're using sizeof(short)), while your C# code reads one byte at a time. A SByte (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x(v=vs.71).aspx) uses 8 bits of storage.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same data type to get the correct output or cast to a new type.

In c++ you are using `short`. (i suppose the file is also written with `short`) so use `short` itself in c#. or you can use `Sytem.Int16`.

You are getting different values because `short` and `sbyte` are not equivalent. `short` is 2 bytes and `Sbyte` is 1 byte

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
{
     System.Int16[] buffer = new System.Int16[1024];                
     for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
     {
         buffer[i] = reader.ReadInt16();
     }                
}
```